# In 2019, is it safe to assume that all terminals understand ANSI escape codes?

Tags: terminal, colors

From what I know, a well-behaved command-line program should examine the `$TERM` environment variable get the name of the terminal emulator, look up its entry in the `terminfo` database, and then use those escape codes to control terminal settings such as colours, fonts, styles, erasing the screen, and setting the cursor position.

However, I'm a lazy programmer, and if I want to make some text green, then by far the easiest thing to do is to embed ANSI escape codes directly in my program:

```
print("\033[32mhi\033[0m")
```

Changing the terminal colour this way is *simple* to implement, frees me from having to learn a new dependency (such as ncurses), frees me from running any external programs (such as `tput`), and lets me write my program in any language that has strings, rather than any language that has a terminal library.

The idealist in me thinks that it's always better to rely on a standard than to rely on one particular implementation. My macOS installation comes with over two thousand terminal definitions in `/usr/share/terminfo`. The pragmatist, on the other hand, has noticed that everybody has been embedding ANSI codes for years now, and everything seems to be fine.

I commonly see code that avoids using a helper library and just uses ANSI codes directly, or software that just checks if `$TERM` is anything other than `dumb`, or software that doesn't check `$TERM` at all. And I very rarely see anybody complaining about this, or requesting support for other terminal types.

Furthermore, I've seen many, many posts on the Internet that make *no mention* of any other terminal types or escape codes, referring to the ANSI set as "how to do bold and colours in a terminal". It really seems like all other escape code sets have died out, and that ANSI codes (or ECMA-48 codes, or VT102 codes) have become the de-facto standard that the development community has settled on.

So, my question is: if I'm writing command-line software in 2019, is it safe to assume that it will only be used in terminals that speak ANSI?

---

**Edit:** People have proposed calling `tput` at runtime to print colours to the screen without having to deal with terminfo at all. This works, and is a good solution in many cases, but in my opinion it introduces an unnecessary runtime cost, as it has to execute a separate binary multiple times right as my program starts.

Comment: I don't see why you can't be correct _and_ lazy. `green=$(tput setaf 2)`. Personally, I always use `tput` rather than hard-coded escape sequences.

Comment: if you use terms like `all terminals` and `will only be used ...`, then the answer has to be `no` ..... all it takes is one misfit to make the assumption false

Comment: "most of the time" is not the same as "all of the time".  Something that only works some (or even most) of the time is broken.  To belabour this point, consider the question: "is it safe to drive my car without working brakes because most of the time I can just take my foot off the accelerator and roll to a stop?".   Often relatively harmless, occasionally catastrophic. so: no problem, right?

Comment: the fact that lots of people write broken code isn't a good reason to do the same yourself.

Comment: @roaima: I find that running `tput` repeatedly starts to slow my program down. I like correct software, but I also like fast software.

Comment: @cas: "Often relatively harmless, occasionally catastrophic". I don't understand — what catastrophe are you referring to? I haven't experienced any problems at all from doing this, which is why I'm asking the question in the first place.

Comment: You haven't experienced any problems because you're using a vt100-descendant terminal.   You have no idea what ANSI codes might do on an incompatible terminal  (or a bad implementation of a compatible terminal that needs its own termcap and terminfo entries).   If you're writing stuff only for yourself for use on your current system, then hard-coding vt100/ansi is mostly harmless, but if you're writing code for distribution, you shouldn't hard-code anything.  It's not significantly harder to use tput or an ncurses lib to do it properly in either case.

Comment: btw, you don't need to run `tput` repeatedly. You store the output of tput in variables and use the variables repeatedly, as in roaima's comment. you might need to switch between green and white text 1000 times but you only need to run tput twice - once for green="$(tput ...)" and once for white="$(tput ...)"

Comment: @cas (Sorry for the late reply on this one) Yes, I know I don't need to run tput repeatedly, but even running tput 10 times is enough to slow it down a little bit! I'd like my program to be as fast as possible, and I'm using a lot more than 10 styles. The point I'm trying to make is that obeying the terminfo standard has a cost that I can measure, while hard-coding the ANSI codes seems to have a more hypothetical cost (it may break for some people). I'm trying to find out how hypothetical this cost is, because so far, all I'm hearing is "it _could_ break", not "it _has_ broken for me".

Comment: I don't see the point of this question. Just announce you support a bunch of known good terminals (or terminal libraries like vte), and be done with it.

Comment: @muru I don't think that's a fair comment. If someone is being held up by having a non-ANSI terminal, I'd rather ask this question and find out, rather than assuming and waiting for feedback, which they may not give.

Comment: Nope, still don't see the point. Either you support some terminals or you don't. If you do, you test on them. If you don't, you never know if some bug in a terminal breaks your code... until you receive feedback.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain myself any further; I'm literally asking for feedback in this question!

Comment: Maybe I should: whatever feedback you get here, you still have to test your code. If you don't test your code, you won't know when it breaks - and it will - and if you don't test your code, and it breaks, what will you do, tell your users to go complain at U&L Stack Exchange?

Comment: The way I see it, either someone answers that they use a non-ANSI terminal daily and would be left out (which would make me find some way to support them), or nobody answers, and I keep doing what I'm doing. I already test my software on multiple terminal emulators, but as far as I'm aware, they _all_ obey the ANSI codes.

Comment: I have found that terminal codes don't map cleanly between `xterm`, `screen`, and the Linux "console". Is that enough reason?

Comment: Turning colors on by default, or worse, hardcoding them (and assuming a dark background!) is already bad enough, I don't see how not supporting it all the terminal _emulators_ can make it worse. But you're well within the trend -- to stop `dmesg` from spicing up my life with yellow text (on lightgray background), I had to create an `/etc/terminal-colors.d` directory and then create an empty `disable` file inside it. You cannot make this stuff up.

Answer (score 10):

If I understand the question correctly, it really boils down to opinion? The following tries to summarize some points worth considering

## Not all output is to terminals

As trivial as it sounds, even if every terminal on the world understands the ANSI sequences correctly (it is not the case as mentioned in the comments, for statements about *all* it is sufficient to find one counterexample to reject the statement): Consider the two cases of redirection to files or pipelining the output trough other programs (e.g. an interactively used `grep` or scripted invication of the programs).

In these cases, it is often desirable to be able to obtain an output which is *not* colorized to simplify processing. Relying entirely on the environment's `TERM` variable can still be insufficient in these cases e.g. a pipeline may be entered interactively which will cause `TERM` to be set but color output to be (potentially) undesirable.

## Colors can be different

I have written quite a few scripts which just output raw ANSI sequences independently of `TERM` (usually with an option to turn that coloring on/off). Using different terminal emulators, shells or even options for the same terminal emulator, I have often received differently colored output. Rarely (but the cases exist and can all be found on modern Linux systems) I have also noticed that the coloring goes beyond recognition (e.g. dark gray on black or such). At times, something that ought to be colored just green had also been applied a "crossed out" effect on it...

For the "fun insight", take any test that uses a lot of ANSI escape sequences unconditionally (i.e. independently of `TERM`) and then run it in: `rxvt`, `gnome-terminal`, `xterm` and finally on the Linux Console.

Without employing one of the abstraction layers, there are always chances that the colorization will fail although the escape sequences are recognized and processed by the target application.

## Conclusion

**In 2019 it is not exactly safe to assume that raw ANSI escape sequences will work as expected.**

Consider how important terminal control is to your application: If it is important (in the sense, that it loses significant functionality without colors/terminal control), the risk for having something go wrong with raw ANSI escape sequences is just too high. If it is not so important (e.g. eye-candy for logs, fancy interactive menus vs. simple interactive menus etc), it seems reasonable to go with a very limited abstraction of colored output (e.g. raw ANSI sequences + option to turn of all colors).

## Other relativizing statements

When the same application that requires colored output or other terminal control sequences also needs to obtain *input* in a special way, then it is time to go for a thoroughly developed solution like ncurses or something more "modern"...

As has been noted in the comments: Only the tested environments are really safe for any software. In case you know the environment, it is always possible (although at the cost of some abstract "portability") to add assumptions to your program that are fulfilled in that environment.

Finally, programs which *are* actually using a more advanced library with terminal information are not safe under all circumstances either: Colors vary with configured terminal color schemes and some effects like underline are just not available with all terminal and font combinations. Then, there are also some cases when `TERM` is being set "incorrectly" causing an application to fail (I frequently experience problems when running a `tmux` over `ssh`).

Answer (score -2):

I agree with the OP's sentiment.  Non-ANSI terminals are, for all practical purposes, obsolete.  If you don't believe me, try getting by with a Wyse or some other non-ANSI terminal in (now) 2021.  You will quickly find, as I have, that you need to use "screen" or some other program to make the programs you are running "see" an ANSI terminal.

Effort spent on supporting non-ANSI terminals is as wasted, and the community really ought to abandon this particular raft of technical debt.

That having been said, there are *subtle* differences between individual ANSI implementations, and you will definitely need to try your program on a few different terminal emulators to make sure you're sticking with well-supported commands.